# uknown character set utf8 in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, xampp, windows-xp

sorry for asking stupid question. I've installed XAMPP ver 1.7.3 in Win XP. It's installed successful. When i open localhost and click on phpMyAdmin, i get an error message

> ERROR
>   
>   Searching SQL : 
>   SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; 
>   MYSQL declare :
>
> ## 1115 - Uknown character set: 'utf8'

is there something error when i'm installing or there is bug on that version ? 
i've already search the error but, most of it said the error is about utf8mb4. 
If this is bug, would you give me any recommended xampp for Win XP ? I've tried ver xampp 1.8.3, but it's get error when i try to installing. 

Thank you :)

Comment: I think this is a version bug. Is there any reason why your are installing such a old version of xampp? they just released `XAMPP for Windows 5.5.19 & 5.6.3` Official Download: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: What MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions come with that? As Lea says, it sounds like you're trying to connect to a very old MySQL with a less-old phpMyAdmin.

Comment: thanks, Lea, Isaac. Because that's not support Win XP. If XAMPP ver 1.7.3 is a bug version, it's solve the problem :) Because i have thought, this version may be bug version :) Thanks a lot for your answer guys :)